# Are packages automatically public after CRAN submission?

Tags: cran

When submitting to CRAN, is it automatic that the package ends up public? I've been working through CRAN errors, WARNINGS, and notes. All the warnings and errors are now clear and I'm wanting to submit to gain CRAN approval, but I'm not ready to make the package public yet (we want to wait until everyone is fine with the manuscript). I'm trying to time everything so it all happens at once and I know that submitting to cran and getting approval takes time (like getting a journal to accept a paper)... so, if I submit, will it end up public or do I get to confirm it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html#Submission

You can check that the submission was received by looking at ftp://CRAN.R-project.org/incoming/. Submission difficulties (such as non-receipt of the confirmation email) can be discussed with cran-sysadmin@R-project.org.

So I'd say yes, automatically public.